# convert ng-repeat to ng-option error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, ng-options

I have this following html code for select tags.

```
<option ng-repeat="option in AllData" value="{{item.Id}}" ng-selected="data.Symbol==item.Id">{{item.Symbol}}</option>
```

I want to convert this to ng-options. can someone please shed some light on this.

the value of AllData is as follows. It is an array of objects.

```
0:Object
 Id: 1
 Symbol: "GR"
1:Object
 Id: 2
 Symbol: "DR"
```

I tried something like this but was not successful.

```
ng-options="item as item .Symbol for item in AllData track by item.Id">
```

Answer (score 0):

when using `ngOptions`, you have to also bind `ng-model` with the initial value of `select`.
mention that since you used `track by item.Id`, the default value should at least contains property `Id` and meets the one of the items `Id` property.
refer the below sample:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.AllData = [{
      0: Object,
      Id: 1,
      Symbol: "GR"
    }, {
      1: Object,
      Id: 2,
      Symbol: "DR"
    }];

    //$scope.data = $scope.AllData[0];
    $scope.data = {
      0: Object,
      Id: 1,
      Symbol: "GR"
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="data" ng-options="item as item.Symbol for item in AllData track by item.Id"></select> {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select ng-options="option as option.Symbol for option in AllData">
    </select>
```

Comment: but i want the value to be selected as option.Id and value to be displayed as option.Symbol